# Need assistance regarding AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

```
        NSArray *pres = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset];
        if([pres containsObject:AVAssetExportPreset640x480]) {
            AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
            FileManagerUtilities *fUtil = [[FileManagerUtilities alloc]init];
            session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[fUtil searchPathDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory byAppendingDirectoryPath:nil andFileName:@"tempVideo.mov"]];
            session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
            session.fileLengthLimit = 10.0;
            [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

                switch ([session status]) {
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                        NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[session error] localizedDescription]);
                        break;
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                        NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }];
        }
```

I am trying to set `session.fileLengthLimit` to 10mb but don't know what mistake I am doing. Unable to limit the size to 10mb, how to set `fileLengthLimit` to 10mb.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value in bytes (ie 10*1024*1024)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fileLenghtLimit should be in bytes, ie:

```
session.fileLengthLimit = 10*1024*1024;
```